# What does [ something ] mean in c#

Tags: c#

I have seen that in some cases we use following syntax format in c#,

```
[something]
void methodM(){

}
```

Example :

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public void SomeMethod() {/* code */}

[WebMethod]
public void MyWebMethod(){/* code */}
```

How this works at the compilation?

Comment: Those are [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: @ChaosPandion When you start from 0, it can be very hard to even take a stab at what something is.  It's very possible OP is new to programming or simply coming from a language that doesn't support metadata.

Comment: @ChaosPandion How is that question supposed to help the OP?

Comment: @R0MANARMY - If you can't even venture a guess that is simply intellectual laziness. The fact that they may be starting from zero is irrelevant. I've generally found that trying to understand what something means using my current knowledge and then finding a true definition allows me to deeply comprehend a subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation

Those are *attributes* or *annotations*. They are kind of metadata for the member they are placed on.

For example, using [*MethodImpl*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimplattribute.aspx) attribute, you can specify the details of how a method is implemented. And using [*WebMethod*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.aspx) attribute, you mark that method as a web service method.

### Further reading:

## [Attributes (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

## [Attributes in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2933/Attributes-in-C)

Comment: The answer is pretty good, but I don't think those links are quite big enough :)

Comment: Trying out Metro style here :)

Answer (score 1):

`[something]` is an attribute. The attributes are stored in the metadata of the assembly and can be read with reflection. This is frequently used by libraries and frameworks to control behavior. Some attributes, like [`ObsoleteAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx) control compile time behavior, but most affect run time behavior. You can create your own attributes by inheriting from [`Attribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

These are **Attributes** [something], which are descriptive tags that can be used to provide additional information about types (classes),
members, and properties. **Attributes** can be used by **.NET** to decide how to handle objects while an application is running.